# Why does gluster require port per brick?

Tags: glusterfs

I am trying to find the reason why gluster needs a port for each brick. Can someone help me understand the reason or point me to some documentation for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is because brick communication uses TCP, and each brick has its own process. TCP can't have multiple processes listening on the same port.